# Ui-Grid - Change background color cells same value

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular UI-grid and I need to maintain the same background color while the value is equals row before. I need to merge colors when values ​​are different, as the example bellow:

[image]

I'm trying to do it using cellClass, but when the user use scroll, the value of the rowRenderIndex is changed and i lost the reference.

```js
cellClass: function (grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
   ...
}
```

How can i get the value and the class of the row before current row?

I created a plunker as a example. In this plunker I want to change the color of column age based on the value of the previous field. If the values are equals, the color needs to be the same, but if the values are different, the color needs to be different as well. If you navigate until line 38 for example, the color of the lines will changing during the scrolling.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f8mk5HKClfrBBbLQg1pL?p=preview)

Comment: What do you mean by "when the user use scroll"?  Perhaps you can provide a working plunker or fiddle?

Comment: @TimHarker, I apologize for the delay, but I was working in another project. I edited my post and created a plunker as a exemple.

Comment: I'll take a closer look.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you fairly close.

[image]

Here's the relevant code from controller:

```
var currentAge = 0;
var previousStyle = 'group2';
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
  {name:'id'},
  {name:'name'},
  {field:'age',
    cellClass: function (grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
        var newStyle;
        if (currentAge != row.entity.age) {
          if (previousStyle == 'group2') {
            previousStyle = '';
            newStyle = 'group2';
          } else {
            previousStyle = 'group2';
            newStyle = 'group1';
          }
        } else {
          if (previousStyle == 'group2') {
            newStyle = 'group1';
          } else {
            newStyle = 'group2';
          }
        }
        currentAge = row.entity.age;
        return newStyle;
      }
    },
  {name: 'address.city'}
];
```

Here's your Plunker updated, http://plnkr.co/edit/gxMGCJTgjVpiY3zRVq0g?p=preview.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks. But do you know why I get several erros in the console? If i go to the line 38 without order the column, the color in 38 line is different the color in 39 line, but the values are equals.

Comment: Good catch, matey!  I updated the answer doing it the way you initially had it done.  Let me know if you see anything else.  Hope I'm helping!

Comment: It's works. Thaks. I'm studying the code to avoid that the cell colors change during the grid scrolling.

Comment: It's because cellClass is running each time it's scrolled and recalculating...  perhaps the cell color change isn't such a big deal since you have only two colours and are trying to delineate like values next to each other...  if you get my drift - although, I do agree it is a little off putting - perhaps it's normally sorted by this column in which case it doesn't happen as often?